# How to programatically change TFS 2010 workitem link-type

Tags: tfs-workitem

I've used the tfs api to programatically add links between work items in different team-projects, currently all links are set as [related links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.relatedlink%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I'd like to change some of them to some of the other types supported in tfs2010 e.g. "parent" etc. But I can't work out how to do it. Any ideas?

Edit:

Originally I added thus:

```
RelatedLink link = new RelatedLink(iLinkMe); 
wi.Links.Add(link);
```

when I think I should have added:

```
WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypEnd = store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"];
RelatedLink linkBetter = new RelatedLink(linkTypEnd, iLinkMe); 
wi.Links.Add(linkBetter );
```

but I didn't, (and I don't like the "Parent" string, I was looking for an enum), so how do I change the linkTypeEnd? I'm guessing I can modify this via *wi.Links* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [site](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc.aspx) on how to `Create Link Between Work Item (Parent, Child etc…)`.

Comment: that's where I originally cribbed my code from. I'm trying (I think) to change the linkTypeEnd of workitems in the wi.Links collection

Comment: That link is how far I got with determining parent/child/related links using the API. :)

Comment: FWIW, in the end I inferred that you couldn't change the link-type, you had to delete and re-add it?

Comment: It's simple enough to delete and re-add it as another type of link. I've also had more time playing with the API and I also haven't found an enum or something for the link types and I use "Child" or "Parent" or "Related" when querying the link types.